# Create iPXE UEFI bootable image for QEMU/Libvirt with custom next-server and filename

Tags: libvirt, pxe-boot, qemu, uefi, ipxe

I can create a VM with libvirt/qemu to boot in UEFI mode. I know that it does iPXE by default, but I want to create/modify a iPXE image in order to override `filename` and `next-server` properties.

How can I do such thing?

**EDIT**:

I tried the following:

`git clone git://git.ipxe.org/ipxe.git`

In the directory ipxe/src create an iPXE script:

Contents of file ipxe/src/chain.ipxe:

```
#!ipxe
prompt --key 0x02 --timeout 2000 Press Ctrl-B for the iPXE command line... && shell ||
dhcp
set net0/filename /pxeserver/loader/uefi/bootx64.efi.0
set net0/next-server <IP>
show net0/filename
show net0/next-server
autoboot
```

Build the image with embedded script:

`make bin-x86_64-efi/ipxe.efi EMBED=chain.ipxe`

Build the image:

```
truncate -s 3MiB usb.img
mkfs.vfat usb.img
mmd -i usb.img "::/efi"
mmd -i usb.img "::/efi/boot"
mcopy -i usb.img bin-x86_64-efi/ipxe.efi "::/efi/boot/bootx64.efi"
```

Then I create a VM specifying this usb.img on the VM storage device. It boots iPXE, prints the `filename` and `next-server` overrides, gets IP through DHCP, then tries to boot from the server, it gets the corresponding bootloader, and then it starts the grub shell, as it seems that it does not try to download any `grub` configuration from `next-server` (double checked on its logs, it only logs the `bootx64.efi.0` file, not `grub.cfg` file at all, as if it does not redirect PXE boot to the second server.

Answer (score 2):

At least on Debian, the iPXE ROM images qemu uses are located at `/usr/lib/ipxe` and `/usr/lib/ipxe/qemu`, depending on which virtual NIC you're using in your VM.

[Download the iPXE source code,](http://ipxe.org/download) make your modifications to it, build the ROM images, and replace the standard images with your customized ones.

Comment: That is kind of what I am doing, but without luck. See above

Answer (score 1):

iPXE has more features than the average bootloader, in this case when booting grub, grub will try to load the configuration from the same location as it was started from, however that does not work due to previously mentioned features.

To work around this make sure to build iPXE with correct config, in this case that is `CONFIG=qemu` which does `#define EFI_DOWNGRADE_UX` (page with some details: https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+bug/1789319/comments/16 there is mailing list threads with more details)

Regarding named configs, See https://ipxe.org/appnote/named_config

You can then either build this as a ROM to replace the original, either by replacing the original file, or provide path to ROM at commandline.
Other ways is to chain from the original to your new one, or as you do now build a usb device.

I think you can even have it in your target to avoid the manual image build step: `make bin-x86_64-efi/ipxe.usb EMBED=chain.ipxe CONFIG=qemu`

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have indicated how to approach this with IPXE, however, given the fact that you are able to get to a grub shell, another answer may be to build a grub bootloader with a preconfigured script, similar to the ipxe script you have included in the ipxe binary. In addition to a standard "grub.cfg", it is also possible to include a "load.cfg", which will be bundled in the grub binaries. See [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Embedded-configuration) part of the grub manual. It may also help to `insmod normal` [ref](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#normal) from a grub shell to load the standard config if your prefix is properly set.