# how to load grub with menu in ipxe setup

Tags: pxe-boot, isc-dhcp, uefi, ipxe

I am trying to setup an ipxe environment on a vmware.

I would like to configure the setup with UEFI.

I have setup a ubuntu-server and configured it as pxe-server.

via downloading ipxe, isc-dhcpd, tftp-hpa and ngnix.

The dhcp isc-dhcp.conf looks like

```
subnet 192.168.101.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
 range 192.168.101.50 192.168.101.100;
}

# add the following to /usr/local/etc/dhcpd.conf 
option client-arch code 93 = unsigned integer 16;

if exists user-class and option user-class = "iPXE" {
  filename "http://192.168.101.10/test.ipxe";
} else {
  if exists client-arch {
     if option client-arch = 00:00 {
       filename "undionly.kpxe";
     } elsif option client-arch = 00:07 {
       filename "grubx64.efi";
     } elsif option client-arch = 00:09 {
       filename "grubx64.efi";
     }
  }
}
```

and tftp root has been configured to serve grubx64.efi.

When I boot a network a client, I get the grub command prompt, where I am expecting to get a grub menu and select OS to boot.

[image]

( echo $prefix, points to folder /EFI/ubuntu , I have also tried configuring the grub in that folder along with grub.cfg .i.e. in root of tftpfolder.

what I am missing here kindly advice, Once I start getting menu I will configure the grub.cfg to load the OS.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to how iPXE works.
There is a few different ways around this.
One answer can be seen at https://serverfault.com/a/1069487/187998 where iPXE is built with some features disabled/enabled to allow for grub to find it's place in the world.

Another is to use some hacks via for example wimboot, to provide grub with a virtual filesystem that grub can use to load it's configuration from, see https://forum.ipxe.org/showthread.php?tid=10739&pid=18277#pid18277

> However there is one hack that works, using wimboot,
> What you do is that you imgfetch all files that you need to have available,
> The bootable file that you want to boot needs to be named bootx64.efi localy which can be don with imgfetch -n bootx64.efi file://grubx64.efi
> and finally you chain to wimboot and that should create a virtual VFAT fs (which can be read by grub), and then boots bootx64.efi which is your grub.

> imgfetch is the same thing as initrd and -n is the shorthand option for --name which you can find in the documentation.

With all this said, you should probably decide between iPXE and grub, and not try to use both.